# How to transform an Excel to CSV using Python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in transforming an EXCEL file (which may have 1 or many sheets) into a CSV file. I was asked to read a Python file (first time I use Python and Pandas) which is in another server to do this request. Searching in the web I found and modified this code:

```
import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_excel (r"/data/IRIS/mgr/PCICODE/ExcelReading/ExcelFiles/Probanding.xls")
read_file.to_csv (r"/data/IRIS/mgr/PCICODE/ExcelReading/CSVFiles2/testFile.csv", index = None, header=True, encoding="utf-8-sig" , sep = ';')
```

This code does the job, but it does not work properly when the EXCEL file has 2 or more sheets, since **I need that if the EXCEL has sheets, every sheet must be in a different EXCEL file**, and the code I am using right now just takes the first sheet and discard the rest. I looked for other options and found this code:

```
import pandas as pd

str_InputFilePath =  input('Name and Path of Excel: ')
str_path = str_InputFilePath.split('/')
int_name = len(str_path)
str_file = str_path[int_ame-1].split('.')
str_shortName = str_file[0]
str_OutputFilePath =  input('Output Path: ')

la  = pd.read_excel(str_InputFilePath, sheet_name=None) 
counter = 0    
for name, sheet  in la.items():
    FileReading  = pd.read_excel(str_InputFilePath, sheet_name=(name)) 
    
    FileReading.to_csv(str_OutputFilePath + str(counter+1) + str_shortName + ".csv", encoding='UTF-32BE', index = None, header=False, sep = ';')
    counter = counter + 1
```

**I tested this last code locally and worked**. It takes every sheet from Excel file and creates a CSV file for every single sheet, but **the Python file I need to use is in another "server" and I can't send it any Input**. So I would really appreciate your help trying to merge these codes. Thank you for your time and guidance!!

Comment: on the server are the excel files all in a folder that you are going to extract from? Where would you be outputting the files to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert multiple excel sheets to csv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559356/how-to-convert-multiple-excel-sheets-to-csv-python)

Comment: `read_file` is a `dict` of dataframes corresponding to each sheet for a multi-sheet Excel file. The linked thread shows how to write each to an individual csv. You should not `read_excel` on the same file inside a loop... read the entire file, once.